# Keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function when using useHistory

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I'm trying to use useHistory from react router dom and I keep getting the error Object(...) is not a function. I tried updating react and react router but I still get the same error. Just writing const history = useHistory() creates the error. Can someone please help me?

These are my dependencies:

```
"react": "^18.0.0-rc.0-next-fe905f152-20220107",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0-rc.0-next-fe905f152-20220107",
"react-helmet": "6.0.0-beta",
"react-intl": "2.8.0",
"react-redux": "^7.2.6",
"react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
"redux": "4.0.1",
"redux-saga": "1.0.2"
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addTodo } from './actions';
import TodoForm from './todoForm';

export default function NewTodo() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  function add(todo) {
    dispatch(addTodo(todo));
    history.push('/');
  }

  return (
    <main>
      <h1>New to do!</h1>
        <TodoForm save={add} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import NewTodo from 'containers/NewTodo/index';
import HomePage from 'containers/HomePage/Loadable';
import NotFoundPage from 'containers/NotFoundPage/Loadable';

import GlobalStyle from '../../global-styles';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter> 
      <header>
        <nav>
          <NavLink exact to='/'>To Dos</NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to='/new'>Add a To Do</NavLink>
        </nav>
      </header>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/new" component={NewTodo} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
      <GlobalStyle />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you've locked your app to `react-router-dom` v5.0.0 specifically:

```
"react-router-dom": "5.0.0",
```

The `useHistory` React hook was added in [v5.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0) though. Here's the related [blog post](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/) regarding the release.

Bump the installed version to ***at least*** v5.1.0.

```
npm un -s react-router-dom
npm i -s react-router-dom@5.1.0
```

If you just want the latest v5 then `npm i -s react-router-dom@5` is also likely sufficient.